# Magento 2, adding price value 1,000 convert and save as 1.00, issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.2.5

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13851

In the above issue, in **Magento 2** they did that on every price field, but they don't do that if **Magento prefilled** those values.
For example, if we can create a duplicate price type field and

> 1. Admin enters the amount as **$1,000** and click save then Magento will save like **$1.00**, and
> 2. Admin enters **$1000** and saves then Magento will pre-fill the form as **$1,000** and then without changing any value click on **'save'** only then Magento will save it as **$1**.

So, My question is, Is saving **$1,000** as **$1.00** is really an issue or Magento does that with a reason?